# Trying to add an item to a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to collect links from a website using Beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

address="http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/2018.04.29.html"
page = requests.get(address)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

articles =[]
for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'cnnSectBulletItems'}):
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        article = link.get('href')
        articles.append(article)
        print(article)
```

[image]

There are two issues:

1. There exist duplicates of links
2. The print command indicates that the code found links, but the list *articles* does not contain any element.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output *as text*, not as the link to an image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
articles =[]
for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'cnnSectBulletItems'}):
    for link in links.find_all('a'):    #-->Fetch Values from links instead of soup
        print link.get('href')
        articles.append(link.get('href'))
print(articles)
```

**Output:**

```
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.21.html
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.22.html
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.03.html
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/rs.01.html
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/ndaysun.02.html
/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/sotu.01.html
[u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.21.html', u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.22.html', u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/cnr.03.html', u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/rs.01.html', u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/ndaysun.02.html', u'/TRANSCRIPTS/1804/29/sotu.01.html']
```

Comment: I see - I should have used the inner loop properly. But why is it that the variable "articles" is empty?

Comment: Is it still empty?

Comment: Yes, it prints fine without duplicates, but the list is still empty.

Comment: Yes, the new code works! Thank you :). I guess the scope of the variable does not carry over to the shell as the list is empty when typing the print(articles) in the shell?

Comment: To upvote the post you need to click the up arrow above the `-1`

Comment: I just did it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Set](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (unordered collection with no duplicate elements) to remove duplicates links.

```
for links in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'cnnSectBulletItems'}):
    links = set(links.find_all('a'))
    for link in links:
        print(link.get('href'))
```